# TinyMCE View Image

Tags: tinymce

I have a website that you can insert an image onto.  I use tinymce for the editor and the insert image function works great.

However I can't find a way for the user to be able to click on the image and see a full size version of it.

I'd like it to popup in a dialog on the page and not open in another window.

Is this a function that is available within tinymce or is it something I need to code in?

Answer (score 1):

This is a function that is avaiable. You can use tinymce popups. Be aware that you need to add [inlinepopups](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aPlugins/inlinepopups) to the plugins and 'dialog_type: "modal",' to your tinymce init.
As example of how to use a tinymce popup you might want to have a look at the searchreplace plugin code in the plugins directory which uses a tinymce popup.

Comment: let me know if this works for you - come back to me when you encounter problems